# (Python) Capture any interactions with an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, decorator, monitoring

I'm looking for a way to find out when a `str` object has been accessed. I want to know when its value has been used by other variables or functions in my code, such as when it was used by `int`, `float`, `len`, `print` or when it was used for additions `result = my_var + 'something'`.

My initial approach was to create a Decorator class, extending *str* and use decorator function to tell me when any of its methods have been accessed. While this approach works fine for `print` and `my_var + 'something'`, it doesn't notify me when I use my object in  `int` builtin function for example.

My approach:

```
def delegate_all():
    def decorate(cls):
        for attr in str.__dict__:
            if callable(getattr(str, attr)) and attr not in ['__init__', '__new__']:
                setattr(cls, attr,
                    lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
                        do_action(self, cls, attr, '_string_value', attr, *args, **kwargs))

        return cls
    return decorate
```

The `do_action` function is where I dynamically set an `accessed` field in my object and then forward the method call to my actual string instance in my object.

And then create a class AccessWrapper:

```
@delegate_all()
class AccessWrapper(str):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._string_value = value
        self.__accessed = False
```

Is there a better way to capture any kind of interactions with my object? Or am I missing something for this approach ?

Thanks.